# Problem with pushing a local branch to a remote Git repository and tracking it

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, gitlab

I know there's a similar question on Stack, and that's what I followed but when I check the Git repository, none of the edits I made appear. The branch I created and edited ("Onboarding") appears to be exactly the same as the master branch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After editing my branch "Onboarding," here's what I tried.

git push -u origin Onboarding

git push -u https://gitlab.com/uw-cocobot/chatbot Onboarding

git push -u https://gitlab.com/uw-cocobot/chatbot.git Onboarding

None of these worked.

Note: Here is my .git/config file.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/uw-cocobot/chatbot
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = https://gitlab.com/uw-cocobot/chatbot.git
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "Onboarding"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/Onboarding
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is happening due to incorrect sequence of commands.

Please try the commands in this sequence:

1. `git pull`
2. `git branch` this should print your actual branch `Onboarding` ---- Does it?
3. If yes, make changes to your file and save it.
4. `git add .`  ----This should add that one file ready to be commited
5. `git commit -m "Making one change"`  ----This will add the commit to your local repository but not remote repository
6. `git push` ----This will push your `commit` to the remote repository
7. Login to GitLab UI and see if changes are reflected in the `Onboarding` branch.